# At a party, 7 gentlemen check their hats. In how many ways can their hats be returned so that at least two gentleman receives their own hats?

Tags: combinatorics

At a party, 7 gentlemen check their hats. In how many ways can their hats be returned so that at least two gentleman receives their own hats?

Ans : 1331

I use below approach but not get correct answer :

[formula used for counting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBPTG.png)

What is the mistake in this approach  ?

Comment: Instead of posting a picture, you should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/10513) to make your maths look pretty (basically, put `$...$` around all your maths-stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot more duplicates than you are removing with your approach. A better way to do this is to find -

No. of ways in which no owner gets their own hat (derangement of 7) $= \, !7 = 1854$

No. of ways in which only one owner gets his/her own hat (derangement of 6) $= \, 7 \times !6 = 1855$

No. of ways you are looking for $= 7! - (1854 + 1855) = 1331$

Or you can find exactly $2$ people get their own hat (derangement of $5$), exactly $3$ people get their own hat etc. and add them.

Based on your approach, the correct answer should be -

$\, ^7C_2 \times 5! - 2 \times ^7C_3 \times 4! + 3 \times ^7C_4 \times 3! - 4 \times ^7C_5 \times 2! + 5 \times ^7C_6 \times 1! - 6 \times ^7C_7 \times 0!$

Comment: 7C2×5!−2×7C3×4!+3×7C4×3!−4×7C5×2!+5×7C6×1!−6×7C7×0!

why you multiply by 1 , 2 , 3 , 4, 5 ,6 each term

Comment: Please take a small number and try. You will know there are more number of duplicates each time. So you need to keep adding $+1$. But I would simply suggest you to use derangement.

Comment: so there is no intuitive way to solve it using only Combinatorics other than Derangement ?

Comment: You can do it but you have to be careful in how you remove duplicates. Btw derangement formula comes from the same principle of inclusion exclusion!

Comment: yup thanks,

so all this kind of problems easily solved using derangement rather than going for Inclusive Exclusive principal where there is a chance of missing some duplicate right

Answer (score 1):

$C(7;2)\times !5+C(7;3)\times !4+C(7;4)\times !3+C(7;5)\times !2+C(7;6)\times !1+C(7;0)\times !0=1331$

$!n=n!(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+... +(-1)^n\frac{1}{n!})$